# what is 2rd argument in React.createElement ? and why it is null most of the times?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, render

I'm beginner to ReactJs.
I can see most of the times 2rd argument to the `React.createElement` is `null`.

Why this element is `null`?  what other values we can pass here ?

```
React.createElement(
  "li",
  null,
  "WhatsApp"
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second argument to `React.createElement` is the the list of props, `createElement` has the following syntax

```
React.createElement(
  type,
  [props],
  [...children]
)
```

Not often would you want to pass props to the `Element` and hence it is set as null. If you do want to pass some props, you could do it like

```
React.createElement(
  "li",
  {className: "active"},
  "WhatsApp"
)
```

You may not need to use `createElement` if you are using `JSX`